# Cs cart global option bulk add to products in category

Tags: cs-cart

Is it possible to add a global option to all products at once?

I create an option, insurance for example and I want to add it to all products in one specific category. It is really tedious work to add it to every single product, since I have more than 40000 of them!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. You can only export all items with product options, correct corresponding column in bulk (for example, in Excel) and import products back.

To check options format, please hover over the "?" symbol on the Administration -> Import data -> Products page